# Unable to get data from Intent in Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am very new to Kotlin and Android Development and really wanting to get into it. I am doing a project to help me understand and work with intent. The goal is simple, an android app that gets the users location in one activity, then passes it on to the next activity, where I intend to use it ( in the form of longitude and latitude). However I have been trying for hours to get the data to pass as an extra. The error that is show says nullpointer:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.tba.mypoint_ofinterest.LocationInfo.<init>(LocationInfo.kt:11)
```

The two files relevant to this are:

1. AddLocation.kt - This is where I get the users location. Then the user presses a button: "btn_accept" and then I want it go to the LocationInfo.kt activity.
2. LocationInfo.kt-This is where I want to receive the location data and where the error message keeps getting thrown.

Here is the AddLocation.kt code:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_location.*


class AddLocation : AppCompatActivity() {

    //variables needed for location grab
    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
    var REQUEST_CODE = 1000
    lateinit var userLocation: Location

    //Deal with permissions
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.size > 0) {
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_location)

        //Check for permission!

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
        )
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_CODE
            )
        else {
            buildLocationRequest()
            buildLocationCallback()

            //Create fused provider client
            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

            //get location

            //start getting location
            btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                        REQUEST_CODE
                    )
                    return@OnClickListener
                }
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                    locationRequest, locationCallback,
                    Looper.myLooper()
                )
                //make the button invisible after clicked
                btnGetLocation.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            })


        }
        //Listen for clicking add location then turn off GPS and proceed to next view
        btn_accept.setOnClickListener {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    REQUEST_CODE
                )

            }
            fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
            locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
                    userLocation = p0!!.locations.get(p0!!.locations.size - 1) //get last location
                }
            }
            var long = userLocation.longitude
            var lat = userLocation.latitude
            addInfo(long,lat)
        }
    }

    private fun buildLocationCallback() {
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
                var location = p0!!.locations.get(p0!!.locations.size - 1) //get last location
                userLocation = location
                txtLocation.text =
                    location.latitude.toString() + "/" + location.longitude.toString() + "and accuracy" + location.accuracy.toString()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun buildLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 5000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 3000
        locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 10f
    }

    //This gives intent and takes the GPS data to the next view to be combined with user input
    fun addInfo(long:Double,lat:Double) {

        val infoIntent: Intent = Intent(this, LocationInfo::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("LAT_DATA", lat)
            putExtra("LONG_DATA",long)
        }

        startActivity(infoIntent)
    }


    //Stop getting location data if back button is pressed
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }


}
```

Here is the LocationInfo.kt code:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.location.Location
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_location_info.*

class LocationInfo : AppCompatActivity() {
    val longitude = intent.getStringExtra("LONG_DATA")
    val latitude = intent.getStringExtra("LAT_DATA")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_info)
        btnSaveLocation.setOnClickListener{view ->saveInfo(view)}
       textView2.text = longitude.toString()+"/"+latitude.toString()
    }
    fun saveInfo(x: View?){
        val saveIntent: Intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(saveIntent)
    }
}
```

I don't think I really understand how to use intent properly or I am mislabeling the loction data somewhere. Any advice is welcome, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to access the `intent` even before the `onCreate()` is called, as a result `intent` is `null`.

Follow this,

```
    class LocationInfo : AppCompatActivity() {
       private lateinit var longitude:Double
       private lateinit var latitude:Double

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_info)
            btnSaveLocation.setOnClickListener{view ->saveInfo(view)}

             longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("LONG_DATA",0.0)
             latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("LAT_DATA",0.0)

           textView2.text = longitude.toString()+"/"+latitude.toString()
        }
        fun saveInfo(x: View?){
            val saveIntent: Intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(saveIntent)
        }
    }
```

You should access the `Intent` in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Ok this is awesome and clarifies things so much. Thank you! Also, I had to convert the lateinit vars to:
`    private var longitude by Delegates.notNull<Double>()
    private var latitude by Delegates.notNull<Double>()`
As it said latenit is not aloud on primitive types. But changing that and it is up and running! Thank you so much! You have made my day

Comment: Ok done! This cleared up some of my confusion on intent. Hope it helps others as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
 val longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("LONG_DATA",0.0)
    val latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("LAT_DATA",0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try that the IDE throws an error saying:
`no value passed for default parameter 'defaultvalue'`

Comment: `No value passed for default parameter 'defaultValue'`
And if I try to run it the error is:
`LocationInfo.kt: (12, 54): No value passed for parameter 'p1'`

Comment: Thank you! Your answer combined with @iCantC 's answer have gotten working. Thanks so very very much

Comment: Yea, your answer was a very important one, thanks for the help +1.